# unregister c2dm

Tags: java, android, android-intent, android-c2dm, android-2.2-froyo

i'm trying to unregister c2dm witht he following onclick on my unregister button

```
public void unregister (View view) {
    Log.w("C2DM", "start unregister process");
    Intent unregIntent = new Intent("com.google.android.c2dm.intent.UNREGISTER");
    unregIntent.putExtra("app", PendingIntent.getBroadcast(this, 0, new Intent(), 0));
    startService(unregIntent);
}
```

In logcat it shows that my Log.w has been hit as it states start unregister process however I can still recieve messages from my server.
another thing i have noticed is that in logcat after this Log.w it starts the registration process again. all the logs from my on register sow and i also get a http responce showing and insert statement.

any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

You didn't set the Intent's package - not sure if this causes the error. Should be:

```
com.google.android.gsf
```

Comment: unregIntent.setPackage(..) ;)

Comment: unfortunatly that is not the answer:(